# Ghostscript: create extra folder for output JPEG

Tags: php, ghostscript

I have the following code:

```
<?php
$path = "/path/file/";
$pathout = "/path/out/file/";
exec('convert '.$path.'test_pdf.pdf[0] '.$path.$value.'.jpg');
?>
```

I want to know if there is a way that ghostscript generates the output JPG and at the same time also generates an new output folder?

Comment: Don't you want to have `exec('convert '.$path.'test_pdf.pdf[0] '.$pathout.$value.'.jpg');` ??

Answer (score 0):

I believe it can not.

Actually you are running a script. In Script, if the target directory does not exist, you will receive an error, like "Not a directory".

Answer (score 0):

Ghostscript does not create directories, so no, it can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

No, Ghostscript does not create new directories. It only creates new files. It can only write these files to existing directories.

It is the task of your script to prepare everything. Your *script* needs to create the new folder in advance where you want Ghostscript to write the output to.